# Event on checkout payment failed

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, payment

Hi I'm looking for **an event to use when payment fails.**

Currently the only idea I have is using the `mage_run_exception` event and checking if it's related to the checkout/payment.

Is there an alternative event or potential model/controller rewrite I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure` it is dispatched in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php` when the order is submitted and you can retrieve both the quote and the order via the following code:

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```